# How to use mass assignment with a JSON field in Laravel based on two text fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

After a user submits a form, Laravel allows for an easy way of mass assigning the model with:

```
public function newFlightForm(Request $request)
    {   
        Flight::create($request->all());
    }
```

This creates a new record in the database.

In my case though I have a `name` field which is a `JSON` type column. There are two user facing inputs, with the names of `name_en` and `name_fr`. I get around this by parsing the inputs into an array like so:

```
$request['name'] = [
    'en' => $request['name_en'],
    'fr' => $request['name_fr'],
];
        
Flight::create($request->all());
```

**Does Laravel have a built in method that can parse two inputs into a JSON combined input?**

Answer (score -2):

Laravel provides an easy way to store data in the form of native PHP types such as arrays and JSON in its models. With this feature, you can define a $casts property on your model and list the attributes that should be casted to JSON. This way, when you create or update a model instance, Laravel will automatically convert the attributes to the specified data type.

For example, you can create a Flight model with the $casts property set to JSON like this:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'json',
    ];
}
```

Now, when you create or update a Flight instance, the name attribute will automatically be converted to JSON. This means that you can simply pass the name_en and name_fr inputs to the create method and Laravel will handle the conversion to JSON for you. For example:

```
Flight::create([
    'name' => [
        'en' => $request->input('name_en'),
        'fr' => $request->input('name_fr'),
    ],
    // Other attributes
]);
```

You can also define a custom mutator for the name attribute in your model. This way, when you retrieve the name attribute, Laravel will automatically decode the JSON string and return an array. For example:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = json_encode([
            'en' => $value['name_en'],
            'fr' => $value['name_fr'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $name = json_decode($value, true);
        return [
            'name_en' => $name['en'],
            'name_fr' => $name['fr'],
        ];
    }
}
```

This way, you can easily store attributes in the form of native PHP types such as arrays and JSON in your models. This is particularly useful for storing data that needs to be processed in a certain way, such as language translations. With Laravel's casting feature, you can easily create complex data structures and store them as JSON in your models.